# Enforcing Outlook 2016 stationery on Windows 10 - missing registry key

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm trying to follow [this article](http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/enforcing-a-default-font-and-theme-in-outlook-2010-with-group-policy-preferences) to use GPO to enforce a particular font for email messages. I'm using a 64bit Windows 10 machine, with Office 365 ProPlus installed (Version 1801, Build 9001.2171 Microsoft Store).

I cannot find the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office` registry key. It just doesn't exist!

Is there a different way to enforce Outlook stationary in Windows 10?

Or is it because it's a Microsoft Store app?

Or is could there be some sort of existing GPO that is preventing me from seeing that particular branch of the registry?

I've been Googling for hours, and I just cannot seem to find any applicable information on missing Office registry keys.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

This key does not exist either `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\policies\microsoft\office`

This one exists `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common`, but the `MailSettings` sub key does not.

Where on earth are the mail settings stored?

Comment: Sounds like you have failed to install the Office Admx template.  Have you done that?  If you create the key by hand does it work as you expected?  All a group policy does is set's a registry key that Windows and other applications are configured to look at.

Comment: If a key is missing it means you don't have the [Office 2016 Administrative Template files (ADMX/ADML)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) installed.  "is it because it's a Microsoft Store app?" - You should clarify if you are using the Desktop or Beta UWP version of Outlook.

Comment: @Ramhound Should I have to create the key by hand? I've already set the required font in outlook, and so I would expect those key to already be present?! Thanks for the info by the way :0)

Comment: Sorry, how do I determine that? Outlook states says it's a Microsoft Store app - I believe that means it's UWP?

Comment: You are right. The Office 2016 Admx templates are not installed. I'm going to do that now. I will update my question accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You should do research so you better understand what UWP stands for.